# parse api tutorial test returns 404

Tags: android, parse-platform

I've started a tutorial with Parse on Android
I've setup the manifest and the init inside App.onCreate

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
Parse.initialize(this);
ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(this, C.REQUEST_CODE_FB_LOGIN);

ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
testObject.put("foo", "bar");
testObject.saveInBackground();
```

The problem is that I can see in my proxy that data is being sent but response is :

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 15 Jan 2016 17:08:43 GMT
Server: nginx/1.6.0
Content-Length: 168
Connection: keep-alive

<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.6.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

any idea why their basic tutorial fails?

Answer (score 0):

Did u login in Parse and check if the object is there in the server.
Here your "TestObject" is indirectly ur DataTable.

Basically u have to create the Object Table in Parse account and then run this code.

To capture the error in Parse use the below code

try this and see whats the response u getting in variable "e"

```
testObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e != null) {
            //Error
                } else {
            //No error
        }
}
```

Comment: @AndroidGecko go to the web console of ur parse account. Create a object/table there and then execute this............ Table Name:TestObject   with one column , Coulmn Name : foo

Comment: thanks, it should not matter as I have "Allow client class creation" set to true